# Ruby on Rails Plural Model Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a domain model that represents flight rules. Flight rules are a collection of regulations under which a flight is performed. Visual Flight Rules, or VFR is one such example. I am trying to scaffold this model, but Rails insists on making `FlightRules` singular (`FlightRule`), while I need it to remain plural. Is there any way of having Rails keep the model name plural?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
rails generate scaffold FlightRules (...) --force-plural
```

You can get the help on the generator with:

```
rails g scaffold -h
```

Comment: I had this same problem, and I had to use this `--force-plural` flag to get the scaffold to create properly, and then I had to add an uncountable inflection to get my fixtures and routes to work properly. See this SO answer about the inflections: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524566/806956 and this blog post: http://markembling.info/2011/06/uncountable-nouns-rails-3-resource-routing

Comment: Make sure to update your inflections.rb initializer too!

Answer (score 28):

You have to edit your inflections.rb file under `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w(flight_rules)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I have tried adding both `flight rules`  as well as `flight_rules`, but Rails still generates a singular model.

Comment: @Laurens : regenerate your scaffold: `rails destroy scaffold flight_rules`, then `rails g scaffold flight_rules`

Comment: I had already destroyed the scaffold prior to adding the inflection and generating the scaffold again, but it is still generating a singular model name: `rails generate scaffold FlightRules (...)` `create app/models/flight_rule.rb`

Comment: @Laurens : I don't know why, but it has to do with the fact that you use CamelCase (FlightRules) instead of snake_case (flight_rules) for your scaffold. Try it again with `rails g scaffold flight_rules` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

[ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) is your friend.

There is a file `config/initializers/inflections.rb`, which you can edit. The file contains commented examples, so it should be easy to add your own rules.