# Plural Name in Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, relationship, model-associations, plural

I have user model and a car model

I want to have a model which will hold the settings for each car and each user

so I do

```
class CarSettings < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car
end
```

for user:

```
  has_many :car_settings
```

and for cars:

```
  has_many :car_settings
  has_many :users, :through => :car_settings
```

note the name CarSettings, this isn't a mistake, I want it to be **settings** and not setting

When I do

```
c=Car.first
c.users
```

I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Car::CarSetting
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
```

it is looking for a singular car_setting and not car_settings.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524509/ruby-on-rails-plural-model-name

Comment: I just saw it, added an inflection still causing it.. I added   `inflect.uncountable %w(car_settings)`

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, did you restart Rails?

Comment: yup, I see the inflection works since it doesn't give me car_setting and car_settings, but I still get that error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force the class name on the association using this option:

```
has_many :car_settings, :class_name => "CarSettings"
```

Comment: Rails will assume that all the model names are singular. So you need to force it to be plural.